# How to execute non-global npm binary in docker

Tags: node.js, docker

Suppose I have following Dockerfile

```
WORKDIR $APP_DIR
ENTRYPOINT ["npm", "run"]
CMD ["start"]
```

The `start` is mapped to `babel-node bin/server`, where **babel-node** is a nodejs non-global dependency binary file (installed inside $APP_DIR/node_modules by default)

On my mac, without any set up, this works fine. But when I run it inside docker, it shows command not found, which is not surprise.

So the same command `npm run start` works on my host machine but inside Docker.

```
sh: 1: babel-node: not found
error Command failed with exit code 127.
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try in this way: `CMD [./node_modules/babel-node/bin/babel-node your app.js]`;

or try to use another way:

```
// you can rename this file to bin.js

const fs = require('fs');
const babelrc = fs.readFileSync('.babelrc', 'utf-8');
let config = {};
try {
  config = JSON.parse(config);
} catch(err) {
  console.error('==>     ERROR: Error parsing your .babelrc.');
}
require("babel-polyfill");
require('babel-register')(config);

// then require your app.js
require('./app.js);
```

then you Dockerfile will be look like as follow:

```
...other codes
CMD [node bin.js]
```